# How to pass in the user in the request for Auth0? (React Frontend and Django Backend)

Tags: reactjs, django, auth0, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I am creating a web application and trying to use Auth0 for my user authentication.
I want to secure some endpoints where the user must be logged in to be able to successfully access an endpoint.

I followed this tutorial on setting up Django with Auth0 and it went perfectly.

(https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/django/01-login)

However though I want to be able to signin from the frontend (React) to be able to access the secured endpoints on my Django backend.

This is what I have for my endpoint that I'm testing.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def test(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return JsonResponse({ 'outcome': 'success'}) 
    else:
        return JsonResponse({ 'outcome': 'failure'})
```

This endpoint is called `path('test/', views.test),` in my `urls.py`.

When I login using the templates and then try to access the endpoint it works perfectly.

**templates/index.html**

```
<div class="login-box auth0-box before">
    <img src="https://i.cloudup.com/StzWWrY34s.png" />
    <h3>Auth0 Example</h3>
    <p>Zero friction identity infrastructure, built for developers</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-login btn-block" href="/login/auth0">Log In</a>
</div>
```

However though the issue is when I try logging through the my React frontend. I can't seem to get the JsonResponse to be 'success' and keep on getting 'failure'.

```
fetch('test/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

I can see that from the backend that we have to do `request.user` to get the user and then doing `user.is_authenticated` to check.

However though, in my fetch request I don't do that.

So my question is how do I past in the user into my fetch request?

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**

**The Frontend Code**

```
const LoginSignupBtn = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [popupState, updatePopupState] = useState('closed')

  const displayName = useSelector(selectDisplayName)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const redirectURL = window.location.origin + '/authorize'

  useEffect(() => {
    // signup configuration
    signupLock = new Auth0LockPasswordless(
      'clientID', // clientId
      'domainID', // domain
      { // signup box options
        container: 'signup-popup',
        language: 'en',
        allowedConnections: ['email'],
        passwordlessMethod: 'code',
        allowSignUp: true,
        allowLogin: true,
        initialScreen: 'signup',
        sso: false,
        closable: true,
        auth: {
          redirectUrl: redirectURL, 
          responseType: 'token',
          params: {
            scope: 'openid email'               
          }          
        },
        theme: {
          logo: '',
          primaryColor: '#ed6641',
        },
        languageDictionary: {
          // Lang Customization: https://github.com/auth0/lock/blob/master/src/i18n/en.js
          emailInputPlaceholder: 'Your Email',
          title : 'Sign up',
          passwordlessEmailInstructions: 'Enter your email to sign up',
          passwordlessEmailCodeInstructions: 'An email with the code has been sent to %s.',
          signUpTerms: '',
          codeInputPlaceholder: 'your code ####',
          submitLabel: 'Sign up',
          resendCodeAction: "Didn't get the code?",
        },
        additionalSignUpFields: [{
          type: 'text',
          name: 'Display Name',
          placeholder: 'A display name we can use for you'
        }]
      }
    );
    // check if user is logged in
    signupLock.checkSession({}, function(err, authResult) {
      // handle error or new tokens
      const token = authResult?.accessToken

      if (token) {
        signupLock.getUserInfo(token, function(error, profile) {
            if (!error) {
              // Setting the display name in redux state
              dispatch(changeDisplayName(profile.email))
            } else {
              console.log('info err ' + error);
            }
        });      
      }
    });
  }, [])

  const signupPopup = () => {
    if (popupState === 'closed') {
      signupLock.show()
      updatePopupState('signup')
    } else {
      signupLock.hide()
      updatePopupState('closed')
    }
  }

  const loginPopup = () => {

  }

  const logout = () => {
    const logoutRedirect = window.location.origin + '/authorize'
    signupLock.logout({
      returnTo: logoutRedirect
    })
  }

  // auth checks for testing only
  const accCheck = () => {
    const info = signupLock.checkSession({}, function(err, authResult) {
      // handle error or new tokens
      const token = authResult?.accessToken
      if (token) {
        console.log(authResult)
        signupLock.getUserInfo(token, function(error, profile) {
          console.log(profile)
          if (!error) {
            console.log(profile.email);
          } else {
            console.log('info err ' + error);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log('sesh err ' + err);
      }
    });
  }

  const testCheck = () => {
    fetch('test/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.SignupLoginWrap}>
        {displayName ? (
          <AccountDropdown lock={signupLock}/>
        ) : (
          <>
            <button className={classes.SignupBtn + ' border'} onClick={signupPopup}>Sign up</button>
            <button className={classes.SignupBtn + ' border'} onClick={loginPopup}>Login</button>            
          </>
        )}
        <button onClick={accCheck}>Acc Check</button>
        <button onClick={testCheck}>Test Check</button>
      </div>
      <div id='signup-popup' className={classes.signupPopup}></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: How does your react app send a user name and password to the Django backend?

Comment: Hello, I realized that i didn't send the user information from the React app to the Django backend. But I've been doing something like this instead. I can get the checkSession information. Should I be passing that information to the Django backend to pass the authentication pass?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some pieces here. Let me explain the overall approach then give some suggestions about what you need to change to get it to work.

First, when you protect resources on your server (the Django code in this case), there are two steps that the frontend (React in your case) need to take to get access to those resources:

1. Authenticate a user.
2. Authorize that user for each request.

There are many ways to handle each of these steps. For authentication, you can send a username and password. In your case, it looks like Auth0 will send a code to the users email which they then have to enter.

In the authentication schemes I'm familiar with, this step creates a token that identifies the user which was authenticated. Then you must send this token with each request to authorize that specific request.

I think you are missing this last part since you are only doing `fetch('/test')`. You need to add to this in order to authorize the user for your endpoint. There are many ways to do this. The most common in my experience is the `Authorization` header in the request.

Comment: Hello thank you for taking the time to answer my question.
So I checked, after Auth0 authenticates the user, it returns a access token. I need to pass this access token into the fetch request and my backend needs to use this token?

I understand how to add the token via the Authorization header, however authorize that user for each request from the Django side?

Comment: @TonyHoanTrinh React needs to send the token with each request via `fetch()`. Then Django will check the token and ensure it is correct and authorizes access.